# lldb-rpc-server in Xcode Version is 10.1?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14 and my Xcode Version is 10.1. When I set break point I’m getting this error.

> Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log
>   is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix
>   'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash
>   log.

How can I fix that? I referred so many answers all they said was
**To print the value instead of setting the breakpoint and another one was to check the mode(debug or release) in edit scheme.** Is any other solution for this ?

Comment: yes but still crashing.

Comment: add the reference link which has not given the solution

Comment: Thanks, Karthik. I just removed all the breakpoints and set to the needed response it's working now.

Comment: appreciate my dear bro, add your answer in duplicate answer